# Meteor: How to detect device model & OS version?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I want to get user's the device model, OS version and screen resolution from my Cordova clients.  Kadira does this beautifully.

[image]

How do I do this in my app? Is there an existing package?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An almost trivial answer without any Cordova plugins or Meteor packages:

```
var device_info = window.navigator.userAgent;
var display_size = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;
```

device_info looks something like "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Mobile Safari/537.36",

Quick and dirty, but all the information is in there and there are no Cordova native plugins to go wrong.

Comment: Probably it wont get you the device uuid though

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device

/////// EDIT //////////////

Well, I don't use meteor, but I can drop you a jquery sniplet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(document).on('deviceready', function() {

        $('#device-platform').html(device.platform); 
        $('#device-version').html(device.version);
        $('#device-cordova').html(device.cordova);
        $('#device-model').html(device.model);
        $('#device-uuid').html(device.uuid);

    });

});
```

Comment: Nice, any Meteor package wrappers?

Comment: Well, I don't use meteor, but I can drop you a jquery sniplet

Comment: Take a look at [the guide](http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-plugins)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I ended finding a more trivial solution which suited me. The plugins would have necessitated all my deployed users to upgrade from App Stores (quirk of Meteor).